# QuickCheck - Non exhaustive patterns in function - Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-platform

I have  two function. One is implemented using patterns and the other using intensive lists. I want to check if the result is the same always with QickCheck.

```
pares xs = [a | a <- xs , mod a 2 == 0]
cuadrados xs = [x^2 | x <- pares xs ]
cuadrados'' [] = []
cuadrados'' (x:xs) = [x^2] ++ cuadrados'' xs
cuadrados' (x:xs)  = cuadrados'' (pares (x:xs))
```

Im trying:

```
prop_cuadrados xs = cuadrados xs == cuadrados' xs
```

When I try quickCkeck prop_cuadrados the output is the following:

> *Main> quickCheck prop_cuadrados
>   *** Failed! (after 1 test):
>   Exception:
>     sesion4.hs:10:1-47: Non-exhaustive patterns in function cuadrados'
>   []

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: `cuadrados'` has no empty list case, so when quickCheck generates the test `cuadrados [] == cuadrados' []` it fails.

Comment: well that is correct, your `cuadrados'` only works with *non*-empty lists, you should use `cuadrados' xs  = cuadrados'' (pares xs)`, or event better `cuadrados' = cuadrados'' . pares`

Comment: The missing pattern is not only found by QuickCheck, but even by GHC itself if you enable warnings.

Comment: It is really advisable to always compile with `-Wall`: like chi says, the compiler can already generate a lists of patterns for which the funcion is not defined.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `[x] ++ y` when `x:y` will do. Also, don't reimplement `map` when you don't have to: `cuadrados'' = map (^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can find that problem immediately if we either apply `-Wall` in GHC (which automatically enables [`-Wincomplete-patterns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-patterns)) or just try the found counter example by hand.

QuickCheck finds `xs = []` as counterexample. So let us have a look at `cuadrados'`:

```
cuadrados' []
```

At that point, we cannot continue, as `cuadrados'` only binds on a single pattern: `(x:xs)`. Unfortunately, `[]` cannot match that pattern and you end up with an error. To fix it, simply add another pattern:

```
cuadrados' []     = []
cuadrados' (x:xs) = …
```

or just use

```
cuadrados' xs = cuadrados'' (pares xs)
```

as we don't use the first element explicitly.

That being said, `pares` is `filter even`, and `cuadrados` is `map (^2) . filter even`. Try to use the standard library and higher order functions a little bit more.

Comment: If you code works, feel free to head over to [CodeReview.SE].